# How to simplify the if formula conditional statement between two sheets

Tags: excel

I have an `IF()` formula conditional statement between two sheets. Would someone help me to simplify it?

```
=IF(AND(I2="P1",G2<1000),(AF2*Rating!$C$12)/100,
IF(AND(DATA!I2="P1",DATA!G2=1000),(DATA!AF2*Rating!$D$12)/100,
IF(AND(DATA!I2="P1",DATA!G2>1000),(DATA!AF2*Rating!$D$12)/100,
IF(AND(DATA!I2="P1",DATA!G2<1500),(DATA!AF2*Rating!$D$12)/100,
IF(AND(DATA!I2="P1",DATA!G2=1500),(DATA!AF2*Rating!$E$12)/100,
IF(AND(DATA!I2="P1",DATA!G2>1500),(DATA!AF2*Rating!$E$12)/100,
IF(AND(I2="P2",G2<1000),(AF2*Rating!$C$14)/100,
IF(AND(DATA!I2="P2",DATA!G2=1000),(DATA!AF2*Rating!$D$14)/100,
IF(AND(DATA!I2="P2",DATA!G2>1000),(DATA!AF2*Rating!$D$14)/100,
IF(AND(DATA!I2="P2",DATA!G2<1500),(DATA!AF2*Rating!$D$14)/100,
IF(AND(DATA!I2="P2",DATA!G2=1500),(DATA!AF2*Rating!$E$14)/100,
IF(AND(DATA!I2="P2",DATA!G2>1500),(DATA!AF2*Rating!$E$14)/100,
IF(AND(I2="P3",G2<1000),(AF2*Rating!$C$16)/100,
IF(AND(DATA!I2="P3",DATA!G2=1000),(DATA!AF2*Rating!$D$16)/100,
IF(AND(DATA!I2="P3",DATA!G2>1000),(DATA!AF2*Rating!$D$16)/100,
IF(AND(DATA!I2="P3",DATA!G2<1500),(DATA!AF2*Rating!$D$16)/100,
IF(AND(DATA!I2="P3",DATA!G2=1500),(DATA!AF2*Rating!$E$16)/100,
IF(AND(DATA!I2="P3",DATA!G2>1500),(DATA!AF2*Rating!$E$16)/100,
IF(AND(I2="P4",G2<1000),(AF2*Rating!$C$18)/100,
IF(AND(DATA!I2="P4",DATA!G2=1000),(DATA!AF2*Rating!$D$18)/100,
IF(AND(DATA!I2="P4",DATA!G2>1000),(DATA!AF2*Rating!$D$18)/100,
IF(AND(DATA!I2="P4",DATA!G2<1500),(DATA!AF2*Rating!$D$18)/100,
IF(AND(DATA!I2="P4",DATA!G2=1500),(DATA!AF2*Rating!$E$18)/100,
IF(AND(DATA!I2="P4",DATA!G2>1500),(DATA!AF2*Rating!$E$18)/100,0))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Comment: Why not write a case statement in VBA instead?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What have you tried so far?

Comment: `DATA!G2` is always going to be both `>1000` and `<1500`. Therefore, take out the unnecessary lines.

Comment: i have tried to write vba but there are circular formulas which is effecting to the remaining columns.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a Case in VBA, as written by Brian.

You could also use named ranges to make the whole thing easier to read (with short names, of course).

Answer (score 0):

This helps but it is still a ridiculously long formula. Use VBA!

```
=IF(AND(I2="P1",G2<1000),(AF2*Rating!$C$12)/100,
IF(AND(DATA!I2="P1",DATA!G2>=1000,DATA!G2<1500),(DATA!AF2*Rating!$D$12)/100,
IF(AND(DATA!I2="P1",DATA!G2>=1500),(DATA!AF2*Rating!$E$12)/100,
IF(AND(I2="P2",G2<1000),(AF2*Rating!$C$14)/100,
IF(AND(DATA!I2="P2",DATA!G2>=1000,DATA!G2<1500),(DATA!AF2*Rating!$D$14)/100,
IF(AND(DATA!I2="P2",DATA!G2>=1500),(DATA!AF2*Rating!$E$14)/100,
IF(AND(I2="P3",G2<1000),(AF2*Rating!$C$16)/100,
IF(AND(DATA!I2="P3",DATA!G2>=1000,DATA!G2<1500),(DATA!AF2*Rating!$D$16)/100,
IF(AND(DATA!I2="P3",DATA!G2>=1500),(DATA!AF2*Rating!$E$16)/100,
IF(AND(I2="P4",G2<1000),(AF2*Rating!$C$18)/100,
IF(AND(DATA!I2="P4",DATA!G2>=1000,DATA!G2<1500),(DATA!AF2*Rating!$D$18)/100,
IF(AND(DATA!I2="P4",DATA!G2>=1500),(DATA!AF2*Rating!$E$18)/100))))))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
=DATA!AF2 *  IF(DATA!G2<1000,INDEX(DATA!C:C,(RIGHT(DATA!I2,1)*2)+10),IF(DATA!G2<1500,INDEX(DATA!D:D,(RIGHT(DATA!I2,1)*2)+10),INDEX(DATA!E:E,(RIGHT(DATA!I2,1)*2)+10)))/100
```